# HIVE multiple rows to columns

Tags: hadoop, hive, pivot

I have a file that I am processing and am trying to combine multiple rows with the same key down to columns in a single row.

my input is

```
rental_company  field_name          field_data      location_identifier
hertz           branchName          ANNABA AIRPORT  RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchCode          AAE             RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           countryCd           DZ              RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           isAtAirport         true            RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchPhone         0555066233      RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursMon      08:00-20:00     RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursTue      08:00-20:00     RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursWed      08:00-20:00     RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursThu      08:00-20:00     RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursFri      closed          RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursSat      closed          RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           branchHoursSun      08:00-20:00     RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           isParticipating     false           RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           airportCode         AAE             RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
hertz           shuttleServiceInd   false           RCCTHERTZAAEREC000002
```

and what I'd like to output is

```
location_identifier                 branchName          branchCode  branchPhone
-----------------------------       ------------        ----------  --------------
RCCTENTERPRISEE10101REC000002       LADUE RENTAL        E10101      (314) 863 6886
```

I have tired using the following:

```
SELECT
   location_identifier,
   kv('branchName') as branchName,
   kv('branchCode') as branchCode,
   kv('branchPhone') as branchPhone
FROM (
   SELECT location_identifier, to_map(field_name, field_data) kv
   FROM vtable
   GROUP BY location_identifier
      ) t;
```

I end up with the following error: Expression not in GROUP BY key 'field_data' and when I add field_data I end up with the error that to_map is not recognized. I was trying to use the following example:
https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/sql-tips#use-of-pivot--unpivot

Answer (score 0):

- `to_map` is not recognized is because,Hive does not have that function.
- Use `[]` for extracting values from the map function.
- vtable is most likely incorrect table.Replace it with your table name.

  ```
  SELECT
      location_identifier,
      kv['branchName'] as branchName,
      kv['branchCode'] as branchCode,
      kv['branchPhone'] as branchPhone
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT location_identifier, to_map(field_name, field_data) kv
      FROM YourTableName
      GROUP BY location_identifier
  ) t;
  ```

Comment: I use vtable here as a placeholder. I use the actual table name when running it against the db.  I have updated it to the above code and receive the following error:
Expression not in GROUP BY key 'field_data'

Comment: What if the elements in the `field_name` are dynamic? How do you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with the following code after having parsed out the table to get the partition date:

```
SELECT 
    location_identifier,
    partition_dt,
    collect_list(field_data)
FROM vtable
GROUP BY location_identifier, partition_dt;
```

From here I will do a join on another table and parse out the data into the correct columns for my final table.